# Caching EAV data - XML or NoSQL / MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, caching, entity-attribute-value, nosql

I'm building a web app that relies heavily on the [EAV pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) for storing data. This basically means that each attribute of an object has it's own row in a massive database table. I'm using MySQL to store everything. This is a very simplified example of what I'm storing...

```
OBJECTS              ATTRIBUTES

objId | type         objId | attribute | value
=============        =========================
1     | fruit        1     | color     | green 
2     | fruit        1     | shape     | round
3     | book         2     | color     | red
```

I know some people hate EAV, but I need to be able to add new object attributes arbitrarily without modifying the database schema, and it's working very well for me so far.

As I think anyone else finds when building a system using an EAV data structure, the weakness of this approach is the retrieval of multiple objects together with each object's attributes. At the moment my app only displays 10 objects at a time, so I just query my EAV table 10 times (once for each object) and it's still very fast. However, I'd like to remove this limitation and allow hundreds of objects to be fetched in one go. I also want to be able to query objects in a more flexible way than I'm doing currently.

Doing this with SQL joins would be hideous, so I'm considering caching the data. On average the database gets about 300 reads for every 1 write, so I think this it's a good candidate for caching.

So far these are the options I've come up with...

1. **XML database column:** Every time a write is performed, update an XML text column in the *objects* table containing all the object's attributes. This would work for reading the data quickly, but querying XML data hidden in a database table is messy.
2. **XML file:** Every time a write is performed, write an XML file to disk which contains each object and it's attributes. This has the benefit that I can then use XQuery to query the objects.
3. **NoSQL (eg. MongoDB):** Perhaps I should have built the system on a schemaless database like MongoDB. Re-writing the entire app to use MongoDB would be quite time consuming, but it struck me that I could use it as a cache. So for example, every time data is written to the EAV store, the equivalent object would be updated in MongoDB which would then be used for reads and queries.

Originally I thought an XML file would be the best approach, but I can see the file getting really big and unmanageable. At the moment I'm leaning towards using MongoDB. I know it seems crazy running two database servers for one app, but I think it could work in my case.

I'd love to hear your thoughts on this.

Comment: PS: I've just remembered a forth option. In the future I need to add a full text search facility to the app, for which I was considering using Apache Lucene. Since I'm going to be updating the Lucene index with every database write, perhaps this could be used for other reads that aren't strictly search related - for example just listing all objects of a certain type.

Comment: Why not simply use the CLRs memory cache implementation?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx

Comment: The other question is, why not simply remove the MySQL Server storage and move to a storage model that can handle EVA better, like you mentioned Monogo or RavenDB.

Comment: @Kolja - Moving over to MongoDB or RavenDB is an option I've considered, but I'm concerned about the amount of time it would take to re-code the data access layer. Also the system is in live production use which makes moving databases harder.

Comment: Then I would just consider using the MemeoryCache. It should be the easiest to implement and doesn't require any harddisc read/writes on cache lookups. And it takes away all the cache expiring handling form you. You can easily configure the amount of cache memory you want to use to find the best value for your Application.

Comment: @Kolja - Just to confirm what you're suggesting, would this mean that I load all of my objects into the MemeoryCache, including all of their attributes? If so, do you know if it's possible to do efficient querying on these objects?

Comment: To me, this really sounds like a case for a caching layer. You can use MongODB, though you may also want to look at Redis (redis.io) or even just Memcache/Membase which are both designed as caches.

Answer (score 0):

I see only two ways, both of them were mentioned in comments.

First, you can really migrate to document-oriented db like Mongo - this is suitable as alternative to EAV. Since it'll be no JOINs and other logic, it'll be very fast and slightly scaled. (So, perhaps you'll be able to avoid using cache).

Second, you can use specific tool for caching like Redis or Mongo or Memcached to save every query result for some time.

But I want to turn our mind to the future of this system. What is planned loading and scaling? 
If you want to reduce system load, I think the best way is to migrate to document-oriented db.
Or, if you want to have result immediately (cache data for reading) - it can be reached by using caching tool, even [if possible] on network level (for example nginx support memcached out of the box).

So, as usual, you should find balance between one-time and continious costs.